# Cant start Kubernetes cluster. etcd and api-server errors

Tags: kubernetes, cluster-computing, kubectl, etcd, kube-apiserver

I've got a broken kubernetes cluster as heritage and now need to start it somehow. I don't know how it was actually created, but suppose that it was done via kubeadm.
So, by `kubeadm alpha certs renew all` certificates were renewed and I made one node partially start, but can't realize what are further steps.
Now I have etcd and kupe-api servers not working (starting and then stopping):
output of `netstat` right after booting:
[kube-api and etcd running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owK8V.jpg).
And in several minutes we have no etcd and api-server listenning at any port:
[no kube-aip and etcd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgSak.jpg)
`docker ps-a` shows that this two containers are starting and exiting in a minute or smth:
[dicker ps -a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yx32M.jpg)

docker logs:

```
2020-11-19 15:10:01.351661 I | etcdmain: etcd Version: 3.3.10
2020-11-19 15:10:01.351731 I | etcdmain: Git SHA: 27fc7e2
2020-11-19 15:10:01.351735 I | etcdmain: Go Version: go1.10.4
2020-11-19 15:10:01.351738 I | etcdmain: Go OS/Arch: linux/amd64
2020-11-19 15:10:01.351742 I | etcdmain: setting maximum number of CPUs to 4, total number of available CPUs is 4
2020-11-19 15:10:01.351795 N | etcdmain: the server is already initialized as member before, starting as etcd member...
2020-11-19 15:10:01.351815 I | embed: peerTLS: cert = /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.crt, key = /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.key, ca = , trusted-ca = /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt, client-cert-auth = true, crl-file = 
2020-11-19 15:10:01.352371 I | embed: listening for peers on https://192.168.1.3:2380
2020-11-19 15:10:01.352404 I | embed: listening for client requests on 127.0.0.1:2379
2020-11-19 15:10:01.352426 I | embed: listening for client requests on 192.168.1.3:2379
2020-11-19 15:10:01.360515 W | snap: skipped unexpected non snapshot file tmp527778953
2020-11-19 15:10:01.362871 I | etcdserver: recovered store from snapshot at index 104718355
2020-11-19 15:10:01.364214 I | mvcc: restore compact to 87110378
2020-11-19 15:10:01.376240 I | etcdserver: name = k8s-master-01
2020-11-19 15:10:01.376263 I | etcdserver: data dir = /var/lib/etcd
2020-11-19 15:10:01.376269 I | etcdserver: member dir = /var/lib/etcd/member
2020-11-19 15:10:01.376272 I | etcdserver: heartbeat = 100ms
2020-11-19 15:10:01.376274 I | etcdserver: election = 1000ms
2020-11-19 15:10:01.376277 I | etcdserver: snapshot count = 10000
2020-11-19 15:10:01.376286 I | etcdserver: advertise client URLs = https://192.168.1.3:2379
2020-11-19 15:10:01.448684 I | etcdserver: restarting member 361c924cbd55a81 in cluster 7e3c896b15fbe02d at commit index 104724993
2020-11-19 15:10:01.448967 I | raft: 361c924cbd55a81 became follower at term 74097
2020-11-19 15:10:01.449001 I | raft: newRaft 361c924cbd55a81 [peers: [361c924cbd55a81,dad85d000dfebf92,e6cf4fe3e32b8396], term: 74097, commit: 104724993, applied: 104718355, lastindex: 104724995, lastterm: 45466]
2020-11-19 15:10:01.449122 I | etcdserver/api: enabled capabilities for version 3.3
2020-11-19 15:10:01.449139 I | etcdserver/membership: added member 361c924cbd55a81 [https://192.168.1.3:2380] to cluster 7e3c896b15fbe02d from store
2020-11-19 15:10:01.449143 I | etcdserver/membership: added member dad85d000dfebf92 [https://192.168.1.4:2380] to cluster 7e3c896b15fbe02d from store
2020-11-19 15:10:01.449146 I | etcdserver/membership: added member e6cf4fe3e32b8396 [https://192.168.1.5:2380] to cluster 7e3c896b15fbe02d from store
2020-11-19 15:10:01.449150 I | etcdserver/membership: set the cluster version to 3.3 from store
2020-11-19 15:10:01.450999 I | mvcc: restore compact to 87110378
2020-11-19 15:10:01.462560 W | auth: simple token is not cryptographically signed
2020-11-19 15:10:01.465418 I | rafthttp: starting peer dad85d000dfebf92...
2020-11-19 15:10:01.465478 I | rafthttp: started HTTP pipelining with peer dad85d000dfebf92
2020-11-19 15:10:01.465710 I | rafthttp: started streaming with peer dad85d000dfebf92 (writer)
2020-11-19 15:10:01.465804 I | rafthttp: started streaming with peer dad85d000dfebf92 (writer)
2020-11-19 15:10:01.465993 I | rafthttp: started peer dad85d000dfebf92
2020-11-19 15:10:01.466018 I | rafthttp: started streaming with peer dad85d000dfebf92 (stream Message reader)
2020-11-19 15:10:01.466035 I | rafthttp: added peer dad85d000dfebf92
2020-11-19 15:10:01.466050 I | rafthttp: starting peer e6cf4fe3e32b8396...
2020-11-19 15:10:01.466058 I | rafthttp: started HTTP pipelining with peer e6cf4fe3e32b8396
2020-11-19 15:10:01.466067 I | rafthttp: started streaming with peer dad85d000dfebf92 (stream MsgApp v2 reader)
2020-11-19 15:10:01.466308 I | rafthttp: started streaming with peer e6cf4fe3e32b8396 (writer)
2020-11-19 15:10:01.466483 I | rafthttp: started streaming with peer e6cf4fe3e32b8396 (writer)
2020-11-19 15:10:01.466637 I | rafthttp: started peer e6cf4fe3e32b8396
2020-11-19 15:10:01.466650 I | rafthttp: started streaming with peer e6cf4fe3e32b8396 (stream Message reader)
2020-11-19 15:10:01.466656 I | rafthttp: added peer e6cf4fe3e32b8396
2020-11-19 15:10:01.466669 I | etcdserver: starting server... [version: 3.3.10, cluster version: 3.3]
2020-11-19 15:10:01.466892 I | rafthttp: started streaming with peer e6cf4fe3e32b8396 (stream MsgApp v2 reader)
2020-11-19 15:10:01.469431 I | embed: ClientTLS: cert = /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.crt, key = /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.key, ca = , trusted-ca = /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt, client-cert-auth = true, crl-file = 
2020-11-19 15:10:02.949569 I | raft: 361c924cbd55a81 is starting a new election at term 74097
2020-11-19 15:10:02.949607 I | raft: 361c924cbd55a81 became candidate at term 74098
2020-11-19 15:10:02.949631 I | raft: 361c924cbd55a81 received MsgVoteResp from 361c924cbd55a81 at term 74098
2020-11-19 15:10:02.949640 I | raft: 361c924cbd55a81 [logterm: 45466, index: 104724995] sent MsgVote request to dad85d000dfebf92 at term 74098
2020-11-19 15:10:02.949647 I | raft: 361c924cbd55a81 [logterm: 45466, index: 104724995] sent MsgVote request to e6cf4fe3e32b8396 at term 74098
2020-11-19 15:10:03.949545 I | raft: 361c924cbd55a81 is starting a new election at term 74098
2020-11-19 15:10:03.949590 I | raft: 361c924cbd55a81 became candidate at term 74099
2020-11-19 15:10:03.949622 I | raft: 361c924cbd55a81 received MsgVoteResp from 361c924cbd55a81 at term 74099
2020-11-19 15:10:03.949631 I | raft: 361c924cbd55a81 [logterm: 45466, index: 104724995] sent MsgVote request to dad85d000dfebf92 at term 74099
2020-11-19 15:10:03.949641 I | raft: 361c924cbd55a81 [logterm: 45466, index: 104724995] sent MsgVote request to e6cf4fe3e32b8396 at term 74099
2020-11-19 15:10:05.749518 I | raft: 361c924cbd55a81 is starting a new election at term 74099
2020-11-19 15:10:05.749560 I | raft: 361c924cbd55a81 became candidate at term 74100
2020-11-19 15:10:05.749570 I | raft: 361c924cbd55a81 received MsgVoteResp from 361c924cbd55a81 at term 74100
2020-11-19 15:10:05.749579 I | raft: 361c924cbd55a81 [logterm: 45466, index: 104724995] sent MsgVote request to dad85d000dfebf92 at term 74100
2020-11-19 15:10:05.749585 I | raft: 361c924cbd55a81 [logterm: 45466, index: 104724995] sent MsgVote request to e6cf4fe3e32b8396 at term 74100
2020-11-19 15:10:06.466249 W | rafthttp: health check for peer dad85d000dfebf92 could not connect: dial tcp 192.168.1.4:2380: connect: connection refused (prober "ROUND_TRIPPER_SNAPSHOT")
2020-11-19 15:10:06.466315 W | rafthttp: health check for peer dad85d000dfebf92 could not connect: dial tcp 192.168.1.4:2380: connect: connection refused (prober "ROUND_TRIPPER_RAFT_MESSAGE")
2020-11-19 15:10:06.467084 W | rafthttp: health check for peer e6cf4fe3e32b8396 could not connect: dial tcp 192.168.1.5:2380: connect: connection refused (prober "ROUND_TRIPPER_RAFT_MESSAGE")
2020-11-19 15:10:06.467113 W | rafthttp: health check for peer e6cf4fe3e32b8396 could not connect: dial tcp 192.168.1.5:2380: connect: connection refused (prober "ROUND_TRIPPER_SNAPSHOT")
```

api-server

```
Flag --insecure-port has been deprecated, This flag will be removed in a future version.
I1119 15:50:49.995997       1 server.go:560] external host was not specified, using 192.168.1.3
I1119 15:50:49.996210       1 server.go:147] Version: v1.15.2
I1119 15:50:50.410114       1 plugins.go:158] Loaded 10 mutating admission controller(s) successfully in the following order: NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,NodeRestriction,TaintNodesByCondition,Priority,DefaultTolerationSeconds,DefaultStorageClass,StorageObjectInUseProtection,MutatingAdmissionWebhook.
I1119 15:50:50.410138       1 plugins.go:161] Loaded 6 validating admission controller(s) successfully in the following order: LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,Priority,PersistentVolumeClaimResize,ValidatingAdmissionWebhook,ResourceQuota.
E1119 15:50:50.410654       1 prometheus.go:55] failed to register depth metric admission_quota_controller: duplicate metrics collector registration attempted
E1119 15:50:50.410689       1 prometheus.go:68] failed to register adds metric admission_quota_controller: duplicate metrics collector registration attempted
E1119 15:50:50.410709       1 prometheus.go:82] failed to register latency metric admission_quota_controller: duplicate metrics collector registration attempted
E1119 15:50:50.410727       1 prometheus.go:96] failed to register workDuration metric admission_quota_controller: duplicate metrics collector registration attempted
E1119 15:50:50.410753       1 prometheus.go:112] failed to register unfinished metric admission_quota_controller: duplicate metrics collector registration attempted
E1119 15:50:50.410778       1 prometheus.go:126] failed to register unfinished metric admission_quota_controller: duplicate metrics collector registration attempted
E1119 15:50:50.410804       1 prometheus.go:152] failed to register depth metric admission_quota_controller: duplicate metrics collector registration attempted
E1119 15:50:50.410825       1 prometheus.go:164] failed to register adds metric admission_quota_controller: duplicate metrics collector registration attempted
E1119 15:50:50.410866       1 prometheus.go:176] failed to register latency metric admission_quota_controller: duplicate metrics collector registration attempted
E1119 15:50:50.410900       1 prometheus.go:188] failed to register work_duration metric admission_quota_controller: duplicate metrics collector registration attempted
E1119 15:50:50.410924       1 prometheus.go:203] failed to register unfinished_work_seconds metric admission_quota_controller: duplicate metrics collector registration attempted
E1119 15:50:50.410934       1 prometheus.go:216] failed to register longest_running_processor_microseconds metric admission_quota_controller: duplicate metrics collector registration attempted
I1119 15:50:50.410952       1 plugins.go:158] Loaded 10 mutating admission controller(s) successfully in the following order: NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,NodeRestriction,TaintNodesByCondition,Priority,DefaultTolerationSeconds,DefaultStorageClass,StorageObjectInUseProtection,MutatingAdmissionWebhook.
I1119 15:50:50.410962       1 plugins.go:161] Loaded 6 validating admission controller(s) successfully in the following order: LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,Priority,PersistentVolumeClaimResize,ValidatingAdmissionWebhook,ResourceQuota.
I1119 15:50:50.412410       1 client.go:354] parsed scheme: ""
I1119 15:50:50.412424       1 client.go:354] scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
I1119 15:50:50.412471       1 asm_amd64.s:1337] ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{127.0.0.1:2379 0  <nil>}]
I1119 15:50:50.412508       1 asm_amd64.s:1337] balancerWrapper: got update addr from Notify: [{127.0.0.1:2379 <nil>}]
W1119 15:50:50.412748       1 clientconn.go:1251] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {127.0.0.1:2379 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
I1119 15:50:51.407920       1 client.go:354] parsed scheme: ""
I1119 15:50:51.407942       1 client.go:354] scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
I1119 15:50:51.407974       1 asm_amd64.s:1337] ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{127.0.0.1:2379 0  <nil>}]
I1119 15:50:51.408003       1 asm_amd64.s:1337] balancerWrapper: got update addr from Notify: [{127.0.0.1:2379 <nil>}]
W1119 15:50:51.408241       1 clientconn.go:1251] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {127.0.0.1:2379 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W1119 15:50:51.412833       1 clientconn.go:1251] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {127.0.0.1:2379 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W1119 15:50:52.408397       1 clientconn.go:1251] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {127.0.0.1:2379 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W1119 15:50:52.987076       1 clientconn.go:1251] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {127.0.0.1:2379 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W1119 15:50:54.057294       1 clientconn.go:1251] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {127.0.0.1:2379 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W1119 15:50:55.505474       1 clientconn.go:1251] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {127.0.0.1:2379 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W1119 15:50:56.454869       1 clientconn.go:1251] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {127.0.0.1:2379 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W1119 15:51:00.038449       1 clientconn.go:1251] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {127.0.0.1:2379 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W1119 15:51:00.372682       1 clientconn.go:1251] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {127.0.0.1:2379 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W1119 15:51:06.682062       1 clientconn.go:1251] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {127.0.0.1:2379 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
W1119 15:51:07.463691       1 clientconn.go:1251] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {127.0.0.1:2379 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
I1119 15:51:10.412593       1 asm_amd64.s:1337] balancerWrapper: got update addr from Notify: []
F1119 15:51:10.412600       1 storage_decorator.go:57] Unable to create storage backend: config (&{ /registry {[https://127.0.0.1:2379] /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.key /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.crt /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt} true 0xc0005b90e0 apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1 <nil> 5m0s 1m0s}), err (dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused)
W1119 15:51:10.412741       1 asm_amd64.s:1337] Failed to dial 127.0.0.1:2379: context canceled; please retry.
```

systemctl status kubelet (it is running)

```
Nov 19 18:49:39 k8s-master-01 kubelet[1074]: E1119 18:49:39.461018    1074 kubelet.go:2248] node "k8s-master-01" not found
Nov 19 18:49:39 k8s-master-01 kubelet[1074]: E1119 18:49:39.561183    1074 kubelet.go:2248] node "k8s-master-01" not found
Nov 19 18:49:39 k8s-master-01 kubelet[1074]: E1119 18:49:39.653030    1074 reflector.go:125] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://192.168.1.3:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Dk8s-master-01&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.1.3:6443: connect: connection refused
Nov 19 18:49:39 k8s-master-01 kubelet[1074]: E1119 18:49:39.661422    1074 kubelet.go:2248] node "k8s-master-01" not found
Nov 19 18:49:39 k8s-master-01 kubelet[1074]: E1119 18:49:39.761566    1074 kubelet.go:2248] node "k8s-master-01" not found
Nov 19 18:49:39 k8s-master-01 kubelet[1074]: E1119 18:49:39.853243    1074 reflector.go:125] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:133: Failed to list *v1beta1.CSIDriver: Get https://192.168.1.3:6443/apis/storage.k8s.io/v1beta1/csidrivers?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.1.3:6443: connect: connection refused
Nov 19 18:49:39 k8s-master-01 kubelet[1074]: E1119 18:49:39.861820    1074 kubelet.go:2248] node "k8s-master-01" not found
Nov 19 18:49:39 k8s-master-01 kubelet[1074]: E1119 18:49:39.962034    1074 kubelet.go:2248] node "k8s-master-01" not found
Nov 19 18:49:40 k8s-master-01 kubelet[1074]: E1119 18:49:40.053584    1074 reflector.go:125] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:444: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://192.168.1.3:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.1.3:6443: connect: connection refused
```

Also I think that option to create new one and transfer application there seems more and more attractive.
I saw there are 8 images (different parts of application) in `docker image`. Will it be a pain to create new cluster and transfer them there?

And where POD configuration can be found? I didn't notice any *.yaml which describes what to do with all these images.

thanks in advance.